# Is there a way to drag around the Modal component from Ant Design version 3.x?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a desire to make the Modal component draggable on the project that I work at.

I'm using ReactJS ("react": "^16.7.0") and Ant Design 3.x ("antd": "^3.10.8").

At the 4.x version from antd, there is a topic for draggable modal. But I can't seem to find it for the current version that the project uses...

Do anyone know if it's possible to do? And if it is, how to do it?

Comment: Does this help https://www.npmjs.com/package/ant-design-draggable-modal? Or this https://codesandbox.io/s/n3x23qxrm4?file=/src/index.js:163-173

Comment: @Lith, There is an anchor for this package in the docs of the 4.x version, but there isn't in the 3.x version, which is the one I'm using